# Comparing the elements in a ListBuffer

Tags: scala, listbuffer

I have two `ListBuffer`s:

```
  import scala.collection.mutable._

  val lstbufWhichChange = ListBuffer("Core", "One", "Zero", "Right", "Top", "Else")
  val lstbufStatic = ListBuffer("Core", "Right", "Left", "Zero", "One", "Two", "Top", "Bottom", "Else")
```

The `lstbufWhichChange` is a subset of `lstbufStatic`. What I am trying to do is, finding a way to compare these two collections, if `lstbufWhichChange` has the elements in the same order like the `lstbufStatic` even if it doesn't contains all of them (it's a subset). How I can do it?

Comment: Sounds like a recursive solution would  work. Check if the first element of lstBufWhichChange appears in lstBufStatic If it does, recurse and check the tail of lstBufWhichChange has the elements in the same order as the rest of lstBufStatic

Comment: Your `lstbufWhichChange` should not contain `"Zero"` because it is a subset. Am I right?

Comment: @srgfed01, yes, you were right. I corrected it, thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do using built in functions can be:
First get the common elements in both the list

```
  val commonEle = lstbufWhichChange.intersect(lstbufStatic)
```

After that, get the elements from `lstbufStatic` which are present in the `commonEle` list

```
  val list = lstbufStatic.filter(e => commonEle.contains(e))
```

`list` should be equal to the `commonEle` list.

In the example you provided, `lstbufWhichChange` has `Right` after `one`, hence, `commonEle.equals(list)` will return `false`. But if you swap those elements then it will return true.

Comment: thnx for this. It's really what I needed. 
thnx to the others also.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is the following:

```
  val res = lstbufWhichChange.foldLeft(true, lstbufStatic)((s, e) => {
    val l = s._2.dropWhile(_ != e)
    (s._1 && l.nonEmpty, l)
  })

  println(res._1)
```

Comment: thnx for this alternative.

Comment: `.headOption.nonEmpty` is the same as `.nonEmpty`.